# Google Actions Builder Many Slot Required

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

Hello guys i need some help/understand how required **slot filling** works.

Looking inside the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/scenes
[image]

I would be able to add as many as much required slots but when I try to test it in Google Actions Builder Simulator (Test) I'm getting this error when I fill only one slot:

```
{
  "insertId": "---",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "timestamp": "2021-06-22T11:46:48.872626Z",
    "endConversation": {},
    "status": {
      "message": "There is no prompt message nor helper instruction in the response.",
      "code": 13
    },
    "executionState": {
      "sessionParameters": {},
      "currentSceneId": "Success",
      "slots": {
        "status": "COLLECTING",
        "slots": {
          "goal": {
            "status": "FILLED",
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "updated": true,
            "value": "goal1"
          },
          "level": {
            "status": "EMPTY",
            "mode": "REQUIRED"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "assistant_action",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "---",
      "version_id": "",
      "action_id": "---"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-06-22T11:46:48.872626Z",
  "severity": "CRITICAL",
  "labels": {
    "channel": "preview"
  },
  "logName": "---",
  "trace": "---",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-06-22T11:46:48.912102599Z"
}
```

For some context I'm using two required slot filling:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can include as many required slots as you like. Once all required slots are filled, `scene.slots.status` will be set to `"FINAL"`, and the pre-populated condition will be met.

For each slot you can mark it as required by selecting `This slot is required`. If you need access to the value, you can write it to a session parameter by selecting `Customize slot value writeback` and providing a name for the session parameter key.

The error you are receiving says `"There is no prompt message nor helper instruction in the response."`.

When configuring each slot, you can add a customized prompt (dependent on slot type) for when you first prompt the user to fill the slot. If this isn't configured, you will receive the above error message.

To add a prompt, under the slot configuration, select `Send prompt` and add what you want to say to the user.

For example:

```yaml
candidates:
  - first_simple:
      variants:
        - speech: What is your favorite number?
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. But it still not working. I have been created an intent Test who has goal and level parameter. For example: test; test {goal}; test {level}; test {goal} {level}. If I just say test it goes to my Scene Test and prompt the first no input slot, The problem is the order of slot validation is important here, if I say in different order it does not work. if I say test {level} the prompt match will be goal not match. Alexa Model works perfect no matter the order I say.